# Calculate Jacobi symbol

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol, jacobi-symbol

Calculate the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{n^4+n^2+1}{2n^2+1} \right)$ for every integer $n>0$.

Using the properties of the Jacobi symbol,

$$\left(\frac{n^4+n^2+1}{2n^2+1} \right)=\left(\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2-n+1} \right)\left(\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+n+1} \right)=\left(\frac{2n-1}{n^2-n+1} \right)\left(\frac{2n-1}{n^2+n+1} \right).$$

However I don't see how this brings me any further. I am clueless, every hint is appreciated

Comment: Multiply the "numerator" by $4$.

Comment: @DanielFisher Why can I do that and why does that bring me furhter?

Comment: You can do that because $\bigl(\frac{4}{m}\bigr) = 1$ for every odd $m$ and the Jacobi symbol is multiplicative. If you do that (right at the start) and look closely, you will see a substantial simplification.

Comment: Not quite, the "numerator" becomes $4n^4 + 4n^2 + 4 = (2n^2+1)^2 + 3$. But $\bigl(\frac{3}{2n^2+1}\bigr)$ is much easier to evaluate (and it will be zero if $3 \nmid n$).

Comment: I see now. Thank you! :-)